# Back-Translation model for German and English

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, machine-translation, data-augmentation, text-generation

Do you know of any pre-trained models for back translation between German and English? I am aware that there are ways to include a monolingual corpus into the training of a machine translation model (often referred to as back translation). I am looking for a model to allow me to generate new, semantically similar German texts by translating them into, say, English and then back. Ultimately, to increase my training corpus with examples that are similar to the existing ones, but with slight variation in sentence structure and word choice.

Obviously, I could just stick together two separate models (one for translating the original texts into English and one for translating the English version back to the original language). However, it would be great if you knew of another that I could use.

I'd very much appreciate any kind of help!